# How to locate element inside IFRAME with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I can't find the search button on the screen below:
[image: type image description here]

I noticed that it is inside an IFRAME in the HTML

I used some methods to click the button that didn't work, it always returns the error message that the element is not found with the XPATH.

follows the elements that I tried to click and commands

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH"//div[contains(text(),'Search')]").click()`

`wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Search')]"))).click()`

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1] /div[1]/div[1]/div[2]").click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to switch to that iframe with something like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='blogger.com']")))
```

Then, inside the iframe you should be able to access that element with code like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Pesquisa')]"))).click()
```

In case there are nested iframes, you need to switch to first iframe first, then to the inner iframe.
I can't give you working locators since I can't access the page you working on.
After you finished working inside the iframe you wil need to switch to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks, I made changes to the first code to work, changing CSS to XPATH

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[11]/div[2]/iframe[1]")))